# "Resource punkt not found" even after manually copying data files into place

Tags: python, nltk

I'm trying to tokenize text on a system with no connection to Internet. I have successfully made use of other nltk data (like stopwords) by copying the *.xml and *.zip into the `nltk_data\corpora` folder. But for punkt, this is not working.

- I found it in an Anaconda distribution in a "tokenizers" folder at the same level as the "corpora" folder and tried mimicking that--no luck.
- I've tried copying the punkt.xml and punkt.zip files to all the locations that the interpreter is saying it's trying to locate the files--no luck.

I know this is kind of hacky, but it's an offline environment with very limited ability to copy anything in, so I need to work with what I've got.

---

The shortest possible code that will reproduce this looks like:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
words = word_tokenize('some text here')
```

When I run the code (in Spyder), out the door I get this:

```
LookupError:
**********************************************************************
  Resource punkt not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

  Searched in:
    - 'C:\\Users\\jchase/nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\nltk_data'
    - 'D:\\nltk_data'
    - 'E:\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Anaconda3\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\nltk_data'
    - 'C:\\Users\\jchase\\AppData\\Roaming\\nltk_data
**********************************************************************
```

(Yes, I typed that all in from scratch).

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll edit. Long day, in a rush to get out the door, was going to post some of the tech details, but ran out of time. Again, because system is offline, I can't copy/paste errors/code, I have to recreate it by typing it in by hand. Having to work in an offline env. is tough, especially because the kinds of problems you run into are not often talked about out here ITRW.

Comment: If I can prevail upon your (plural) better nature, I would appreciate reversal of the down-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to bug everyone, but I found the answer. I traced the error back to data.py in the nltk distribution where it was working with a path:

```
def _open(resource_url)
    ...
```

I inspected this resource_url and found that the file/path it's looking for is:

```
nltk:tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle
```

So I unzipped punkt.zip into the folder tokenizers/punkt (full path is C:\Anaconda3\Lib\nltk_data\tokenizers\punkt) and that got me past the error.

This question and my answer may lead the pros in the world of Python to make comments about how my environment seems to have some issues. To that, I would agree. It's a VM I didn't build and don't have a lot of control over.

Again, sorry for the false alarm. I should have just let it lie until the morning when everything's fresh.